# Getting reference to the raw array from std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

What's the canonical way to get the reference to `std::array`'s  underlying raw (C) array?

The `data()` method returns just a raw pointer, which makes it unsuitable e.g. for passing into functions which accept a reference to a raw array of a known size.

Also, is there a good reason why `data()` returns a raw pointer, and not a reference to the underlying raw array, or is this just an oversight?

Comment: Passing around references to sized arrays is tricky, and not widely used; why would they be, since you would only use a raw array to interact with C code, which has no references anyway?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: The OP means there is no way to turn a `std::array<int,5>` into something that can be passed to `myFunc( int (&k)[5])`.  (A reference to an array of 5 ints).

Comment: Well, it may be because the committee designed `std::array` as a superior alternative. Disallowing to easily get a reference to the underlying raw array may just be a nudge in the direction they want us to program.

Comment: I think the changed wording is much better.  The answer to the previous wording was 'use `data()`'

Comment: In C an `array` **is** a pointer, the size is just some good advice. I don't get what you mean by a reference to that?

Comment: @kabanus: No, it's not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I never understood why people insist on these subtleties. The only place I could think of a difference (from the coders perspective) is the use of `sizeof` operator. If you have a link to a resource that explains another reason to treat them differently I would appreciate it.

Comment: @kabanus - These "subtleties" in C are the difference between passing a multidimensional array to a function correctly, as opposed to getting a weird pointer conversion error or a segfault.

Comment: Not pretty, but possible [`getRaw()`](http://ideone.com/kKAiJS).

Comment: @StoryTeller Can I take you to the chat for a second? if there is really a problem with accepting a **something and two int sizes in a function I would like to know why. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/132293/c-talk?tab=general

Comment: @k​​​​​​​​​​​​​abanus: It's not a "subtlety". You made a claim that is incorrect, and the claim fosters misunderstanding. For example, this is precisely why you "don't get what [we] mean by a reference to [an array]", because you are thinking of arrays (in either language) as something that they are not.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Is that well-defined?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Kinda sorta? It's casting a pointer to a single element into a pointer to `N` consecutive ones. So I think `(*arr)[0]` should refer to the first element of the `N`, same as `*(arr.data())` does. But I don't have a standard quote to back me up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It seems not, per this note in [basic.compound]/4: "An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible."

Comment: @Oktalist: You got it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51426068/412080

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What's the canonical way to get an std::array's underlying raw (C)
>   array?

There is no way of getting the underlying C array.

> Also, is there a good reason why data() returns a raw pointer, and not
>   a reference to the underlying raw array, or is this just an oversight?

It's backwards: there is no good reason for the `std::array` to provide the underlying C array. As you already said, the C array would be useful (over the raw pointer) only with functions getting a reference to C arrays.

When was the last time you had a function:

```
void foo(int (&arr)[5])
```

Me? Never. I never saw a function with a C array reference parameter with the exception of getting the size of array (and rejecting pointers):

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
auto safe_array_size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

---

Let's dive a little into why parameters references to arrays are not used.

For starters, from the C area pointer with a separate size parameter was the only way to pass arrays around, due to array-to-pointer decay and lack of reference type.

In C++ there are alternatives to C arrays, like `std::vector` and `std::array`. But even when you have a (legacy) C array you have 2 situations:

- if you pass it to a C function you don't have the option of reference, so you are stuck to pointer + size
- when you want to pass it to a C++ function the idiomatic C++ way is to pass begin + end pointers.

First of all a begin + end iterators is generic, it accepts any kind of containers. But is not uncommon to see reference to `std::vector` when you want to avoid templates, so why not reference to C array if you have one? Because of a big drawback: you have to know the size of the array:

```
void foo(int (&arr)[5])
```

which is extremely limiting.

To get around this you need to make it a template:

```
template <std::size N>
void foo(int (&arr)[N])
```

which beats the purpose of avoiding templates, so you better go with begin + end template iterators instead.

---

> In some cases (e.g. math calculations on just 2 or 3 values which have
>   the same semantics, so they shouldn't be separate parameters) a
>   specific array size is called for, and making the function generic
>   wouldn't make sense. In those cases, specifying the size of the array
>   guarantees safety since it only allows passing in an array of the
>   correct size at compile-time; therefore it's advantageous and isn't a
>   "big drawback"

One of the beauties of (C and) C++ is the enormous scope of applicability. So yes, you will always find some fields that use or need a certain unique feature in an unique way. That being said, even in your example I would still shy away from arrays. When you have  a fixed number of values that shouldn't be semantically separated I think a structure would be the correct choice over arrays most of the time (e.g. `glm::mat4` instead of `float[4]`).

But let's not forget what `std::array` is: a modern replacement for C arrays. One thing I learned when analyzing options is that there is no absolute "better than". There is always a "depends". But not in this case: `std::array` should unquestionably replace C arrays in interfaces. So in the rare case where a fixed size container is needed as a reference parameter it doesn't make sense to enable encouraging the use of C arrays when you already have an `std::array`. So the only valid case where exposing the underlying C array of `std::array` is need is for some old libraries that have C array reference parameters.  But I think that in the bigger picture adding this to the interface it is not justified. New code should use a struct (btw `std::tuple` is getting easier and easier to use by each standard) or `std::array`.

Comment: In some cases (e.g. math calculations on just 2 or 3 values which have the same semantics, so they shouldn't be separate parameters) a specific array size is called for, and making the function generic wouldn't make sense. In those cases, specifying the size of the array guarantees safety since it only allows passing in an array of the correct size at compile-time; therefore it's advantageous and isn't a "big drawback".

Comment: I'd just like to point out that even in the C area, [it's possible to take a _pointer_ to an array of a specific size, using nearly-identical syntax to taking a reference to an array of a specific size in C++](http://rextester.com/MHUBK79249); unfortunately, passing a pointer to a differently-sized array is treated as a warning instead of an error in every compiler I'm aware of.

Comment: `(T(&)[N])*a.data()` works, see [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df75771c8c1e4f19). That doesn't make it very practical though.

Answer (score 3):

You can `reinterpret_cast` the `.data()` to a raw, like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline static decltype(auto) to_raw_array(const std::array<T, N> & arr_v) {
        return reinterpret_cast<const T(&) [N]>(*arr_v.data());
}
```

But it is an ugly hack. As the others have already suggested, I recommend you to use `std::array` as-is.

Usage:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline static decltype(auto) to_raw_array(const std::array<T, N> & arr_v) {
        return reinterpret_cast<const T(&) [N]>(*arr_v.data());
}

void foo(const std::uint8_t(&buf)[5]){
   // ...
}

int main(void){
   std::array<std::uint8_t, 5> arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
   foo(to_raw_array(arr));
}
```

Comment: This is UB. Even adding `std::launder` cannot help. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47926463/3966456

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, There's no direct or typesafe way to do it, but one work around if you need to pass to a function (with a signature you cannot change to `std::array`) is by using`reinterpret_cast` like this:

```
some_function(*reinterpret_cast<int (*)[myarr.size()]>(myarr.data())));
```

If you wanted to make it safer:

```
#include <array>

void passarray(int (&myarr)[5]){}  

template <typename ValueT, std::size_t size>  
using CArray = ValueT[size];  

template <typename ValueT, std::size_t size>  
CArray<ValueT, size> & c_array_cast(std::array<ValueT, size> & arg)  {
{                                      
    return *reinterpret_cast<CArray<ValueT,size>*>(arg.data());  
}  

int main()
{  
    std::array<int,5> myarr = { {1,2,3,4,5} };  

    passarray(*reinterpret_cast<int (*)[myarr.size()]>(myarr.data()));  
    passarray(c_array_cast(myarr));  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, is there any particular reason for using `*reinterpret_cast<int (*)[myarr.size()]>(myarr.data())` instead of just `reinterpret_cast<int*>(myarr.data())`?

Comment: This is UB according to https://stackoverflow.com/q/47926463/3966456

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.

I can see why it would be useful, especially when working with legacy code, but since a couple of decades ago we're supposed to be moving away from code like that and towards iterator-aware algorithms. And when working with C code you'd have to use a pointer anyway. I presume these are factors in the decision not to provide this functionality.

Rewrite your code to accept `std::array<T, N>&` instead, if possible.

Answer (score -3):

Why not passing `std::array.begin()`? Worked in SDL2 on:

```
int SDL_RenderDrawLines(SDL_Renderer *renderer, const SDL_Point *points, int count)
```

My line to be drawed:

```
std::array<SDL_Point, 8> a_line;
```

I passed like this:

```
SDL_RenderDrawLines(r_s_game.p_renderer, a_line.begin(), 8);
```

Comment: The only useful answer here

Comment: `begin` returns an iterator, not a pointer