# Why do c++ standard not guarantee pointer-interconvertibility between an array of objects and its first element?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast

According to this

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4

> Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> - they are the same object, or
> - one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([class.union]), or
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object ([class.mem]), or
> - there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_­cast.
> [ **Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address.**
> — end note ]

Why do c++ standard not guarantee pointer-interconvertibility between an array of objects and its first element whereas do guarantee class and its 1st member ?

How come this is undefined behavior?

```
char carr[8];
char& ch0 = carr[0];
auto& carr2 = reinterpret_cat<char (&) [8]>(ch0); // Is this considered undefined behavior?

// Because ch0 (char&) and carr2 (char(&)[8]) are not "pointer-interconvertible".
// So they can not use reinterpret_cast "definedly".
// Array and its first element are not "pointer-interconvertible"
// eventhough they share the same address.
```

While this is an example on the standard itself.

http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#2

```
#define N sizeof(T)
char buf[N];
T obj;                          // obj initialized to its original value
std::memcpy(buf, &obj, N);      // between these two calls to std​::​memcpy, 
                                // obj might be modified
std::memcpy(&obj, buf, N);      // at this point, each subobject of obj
                                // of scalar type holds its original value
```

Think if T = char[N]? Well, wouldn't &obj become char(&)[N]? Why is std::memcpy so superior that it can use char(&)[N] while we can't.

This is so amusing.

I'm eager to know why the standard intentionally make `char *` and `std::memcpy` **only** tools to iterate storage by bytes.

Comment: because, in general,  it violates strict aliasing rules ?

Comment: this was already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924103/pointer-interconvertibility-vs-having-the-same-address

Comment: If you thing an Array is *just* a Pointer, try to compare  `sizeof(carr)` and `sizeof(ch0)`. I am not sure about why it works between aclass and its first member though.